# How do I calculate Compound interest with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, simulator

I'm creating a compound interest simulator. I want the simulator to solve the problem where the principal amount in the formula is 10,000,000.00, the monthly contribution is 500,000.00, the interest rate is 12 %(annually) or 0.95 % (monthly) and the time is 5 years. I tried translating the formula to a javascript code, but the calculation results where wrong every time, so I butchered the code to simplify the calculations and had no luck.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**This is my JS code:**

```
// get input values
var principal = parseFloat(principalInput.value.replace(/[^0-9,-]+/g,"").replace(",","."));
var deposit = parseFloat(depositInput.value.replace(/[^0-9,-]+/g,"").replace(",","."));
var taxa = parseFloat(taxaInput.value.replace(",", "."));
var interestRateType = taxaTypeSelect.value;
var periodo = parseFloat(periodoInput.value);
var timePeriodType = periodoTypeSelect.value;

// convert time period to months if necessary
if (timePeriodType === "anos") {
  periodo = periodo * 12;
}

// calculate interest rate per period
var r = taxa / 100;
if (interestRateType === "anual") {
  r /= 12;
}

// calculate total invested
var totalInvested = principal;
var balance = principal;
for (var i = 0; i < periodo; i++) {
  var interest = balance * r;
  balance += deposit + interest;
  totalInvested += deposit;
}


// calculate final total
var a = (1 + r).toFixed(11) ** periodo; 
console.log("Part A: "+a);
console.log("A(1) : "+(1 + r));
var b = ((1 + r).toFixed(11) ** periodo - 1) / r; 
console.log("Part B: "+b);
console.log("B(1): "+(Math.pow(1 + r, periodo) - 1));
var c = principal*a; 
console.log("Part C: "+c);
var d = deposit *b; 
console.log("Part D: "+d);



var finalAmount = c + d;

// calculate total interest
var totalInterest = finalAmount - totalInvested;

// display results
valorFinalSpan.textContent = 'KZ ' + finalAmount.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
valorInvestidoSpan.textContent = 'KZ ' + totalInvested.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
totalJurosSpan.textContent = 'KZ ' + totalInterest.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
```

I was expecting the final amount to be 57,794,052.26, but I keep getting 59,001,801.91 instead and would like to know why.

Comment: I tried your code with 10,000,000.00, 500,000.00, 12% over 5 years and the total was 560603.00. Maybe you just need to check your numbers. Also your expected result should be 55,740,500.99.

Comment: @André Thanks, but I would appreciate it if you show me how you ended up with '55,740,500.99'.

Comment: I used this tool: https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator

Comment: @André, I'm so confused. I used official site's tool:https://www.mobills.com.br/calculadoras/calculadora-juros-compostos/resultado/?valor-inicial=10000000&valor-mensal=500000&taxa-de-juros=0.009488792934583046&juros_tipo=Anual&periodo=60&periodo_tipo=Anos&juros=12%2C00
And I'm getting a different result. Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: I added an explanation on my answer and also the code to achieve the result you wanted. Let me know if it works, and if it does you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your result of `59,001,801.91` is correct for interest compounded monthly. You can test this [here](https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator), make sure you select Monthly compound frequency.
The value of `57,794,052.26` you sugested, is the interest compounded semmianually or every six months. If you want to achieve this result you have to adjust your rate to a 12 % semiannualized rate:

```
if (interestRateType === "mensal") { // this should be changed to "mensal" becasue is compounded monthly
  r /= 12;
} else if (interestRateType === "semianual") {
  r = (r + 1) ** (1/12) - 1;
}
```

The rest of your code will work as intended.